# How to iterate over a mongoose table?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this schema, email is the primary key. The manager column holds the email of the manager. When a manager logs into his account I need to find the list of all employees in the table where he is the manager. If a manager does not have a manager, I put some dummy text. I need to iterate over the table and get an array of Users or any other structure through which I can iterate. I will be passing this into ejs and printing the list.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        },
        email: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        },
        password: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        },
        manager: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I tried doing something like a join using populate, which didn't work. I later realized I can simply iterate over the table. I'm not completely sure if iterating over the table is safe, is using something else safer in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass all the users into the ejs template for rendering you could do something as simple as this :-

```
const users = await User.find({manager : '<managerName>' })
res.render('template', {users : users})
```

Then in your ejs template you could iterate over this array

```
<% users.forEach( user => { %>
<p><%=user.name%></p>
// Do other stuff with the user
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.statics.findKey({}, (err, users) => {
        if(err) {
                next(err);
        }
        users.map(user => {
          //iterate
        })
})
```

I figured it out, went through the documentation.